# no-await-in-loop, advice about alternative solution

Tags: express, asynchronous, mongoose, eslint

I'm using Express with mongoose for my application, and I'm using ESLint. I have in my app :

- Some categories, defined by a name, an id, and some external categorie's ids to match with
- Some events, defined by a name and a category

I'm doing something like this to get the category while creating event from json :

```
let promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
   const event = new Event({
      name: events[i].name,
      category: await Category.findOne({externalSource: events[I].category_id})
   });
   promises.push(event.save());
}
Promise.all(promises)...
```

My code is working, but ESLint throw the error `no-await-in-loop`. I deactivated it with `/* eslint-disable no-await-in-loop */` but I would like to know what are the good alternative solution I have to do this while respecting the ESLint constraint ?

I was thinking about a pre-save hook in mongoose to set the category if none is already defined but I don't know if it's good practice and I think it might have some side effects

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` in loops will not allow each operation to execute parallelly(almost). You should use it only when you want the previous operation to get completed before the next one in the loop.

Being said that, `await` will wait till it gets the current request's response before the next operation. Whereas you can fire the operations parallelly or one after the other with a counter variable should be enough to solve your issue:

```
let tasks = [];
var counter = 0
for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
  Category.findOne({externalSource: events[i].category_id}).then(d => {
    counter++
    tasks.push(new Event({
      name: events[i].name,
      category: d
    }).save())
    if(counter === events.length){
      Promise.all(tasks).then(allData => {
        console.log('Done', allData)
      }).catch(console.error)
    }
  }).catch(console.error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't really like this approach because I think it make the code more complicated to read but it's seems to be a good solution in term of performance, I'm gonna switch for something like that